# Is more Reactive better?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Given a method I can write reactive code in two ways:

```
public String getString() { return "Hello, World"; }
```

or

```
public Mono<String> getMonoString() { return Mono.just("Hello, World"); }
```

And then use it with either

```
someOtherPublisher.map( value-> getString() + value ).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

or

```
someOtherPublisher.flatMap( value-> getMonoString().map(str-> str + value ) ).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

My question is whether more reactive is better? I was arguing that the extra overhead of `getMonoString` was worse because of overhead and performance and the other was arguing that having methods be publishers and using `.flatMap` was better because it was "more reactive".

I am interested in finding some authority on why one is better or worse than the other or even whether it matters.

Clearly I could do some simple tests but sometimes simple tests can fail to be convincing.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but where is `Mono<T>` defined?

Comment: import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

Comment: There is absolutely zero point in using the "more reactive" approach in this example - it's greater code complexity for no gain.

Comment: My feeling as well. What would you refer someone to that is not clear on this?

Comment: @K.Nicholas To any basic tutorial on reactive programming - the key bit being that these tools and methods exist in order to avoid blocking code. If there's no blocking code as in the above example, then there's no gain.

Answer (score 3):

first of all.

```
public String getString() { return "Hello, World"; }
```

this is not reactive. This is a standard imperative function, that has 0(1) time complexity. So over `n` number of runs this will perform sort of the same.

This is reactive:

```
public Mono<String> getMonoString() { return Mono.just("Hello, World"); }
```

But this also has 0(1) time complexity. Which means, that there is a possibility that it will switch threads in the middle of it, but the chance is very unlikely. Over `n` number of runs this will also perform sort of the same.

**None of your examples matter, because non of them actually take any time.**

When reactive shines is when dealing with side effects. **Things that take time**, like database calls, http calls, File I/O etc. etc.

**Reactive is good when threads need to wait.**

Comment: True for "first of all" and presented as a simple example, not as actual examples. The "real world" versions are still essentially O(1) methods, but could "take time". So, you mean to say that reactive is good when "threads need to block". Is there something that says "don't create publishers in your code if it isn't blocking for some reason." Perhaps something that says what reactive is and isn't good for. Thanks.

Comment: No there is no such thing that you are looking for. Reactive is all about maximising each threads workload. With as little wait time as possible.